# How to make a MySQL query in Qt?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm trying to create a simple app which allows user to enter a word and the app will output the definition. I have compiled words and definitions by making mysql database file. I thought using MySQL would be a faster way make my app. My database looks like this:

```
rowed      |  Column1(word)           | Column2(definition)
1               DNA                      A double-stranded,helical...
```

The pseudocode for this program definitely should be like this:

```
if(lineEdit == wordInput)
{ 
    ui->label->setText("Display definition)
}
```

I just can't figure out how to do it. So far I have tried following code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPalette>

#define Path_to_DB "/Users/makkhay/Desktop/nep_eng-2.sqlite"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
       // Set background picture
       QPixmap bkgnd("/Users/makkhay/Desktop/background.jpg");
       bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
       QPalette palette;
       palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
       this->setPalette(palette);


       myDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
       myDB.setDatabaseName(Path_to_DB);
       QFileInfo checkFile(Path_to_DB);

       if(checkFile.isFile())
       {
           if(myDB.open())
           {
             ui->label->setText("The database is connected");
           }

       }else{
           ui->label->setText("No file found!");
       }


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    myDB.close();
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
//    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply= QMessageBox::question(this,
//                                      "My Title", " Word not found, quit app?",
//                                       QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);


//    if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes){

//        QApplication::quit();
//}


    if(!myDB.isOpen()){
        qDebug() << " No connection to db";
        return;
    }

    QString wordInput, definition;
    wordInput = ui->lineEdit->text();

    QSqlQuery qry;

    qry.prepare("SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM Nepali WHERE Column1  = :input");
    qry.bindValue(":input",wordInput);
   // int fieldNo = query.record().indexof("Column1");

    if(qry.exec())
    {
        ui->debug->setText(" Checking output!");  // output is visible 

      while (qry.next())
       {
         ui->output->setText("Checing output!");  // output is not visible


        QString inputWord = qry.value(0).toString();
        QString wordDefinition = qry.value(1).toString();
        ui->output->setText(wordDefinition);





      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you compiled the MySQL driver from the Qt source code?

Comment: What do you mean when you say mysql driver?

Comment: Do you call db.open() anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yeah I have used that , and it also checks whether the database is loaded. If the database is loaded then it will output " the database is loaded" if not then " Failed to load". And mine says it is loaded, and I have messing up path and I can confirm that it does work.

Comment: Ok, so your are using SQLite, and you have a .sqlite3 or a .db file located at Path_to_DB.  And I assume the label indicates that the database connected.  Or does the label not change?

Comment: Yes the label does indicate that it is connected

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it before, but the SQL statement should just need FROM to specify the name of the table to select from.  See my edited/updated answer below, and try the new prepared statement, but with 'tableName' replaced by the name of your table

Comment: Just tried that statement, and the first line if(qry.exec()) is now returning true, that means I can output a text. However, the second if statement  if (qry.next()) is still false. Thus, can't output any text.

Comment: Is there data in the database?  If qry.next() is false that means there is no data in the database that matches your query.  Try querying 'SELECT * FROM tableName' and see if query.next() is true.  If there is data in the database, it will be true.

Comment: There is data in my database. I have viewed content using database software.

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: I have included my whole source code, please take a look.

Comment: Try adding the header files I suggested in my new answer if you haven't included those yet.  Also, remove the last line ' ui->output->setText(wordDefinition);' from your code for now.  It replaces the checking output text that your using to see if qry.next() was true.

Comment: Okay I removed the line ui->output->setText(wordDefinition);  and added the header files that you mentioned. Still no luck.

Comment: where do you declare myDB at?

Comment: it is declared at my header file  mainwindow.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the following code works for me.  Try commenting out your existing code and pasting this code in.  This code is basically the exact same code you posted, I just commented out some of the code to set the background and removed some excess lines.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QFileInfo>

#define Path_to_DB "/Users/makkhay/Desktop/nep_eng-2.sqlite"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
       // Set background picture
       //QPixmap bkgnd("/Users/makkhay/Desktop/background.jpg");
       //bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
       //QPalette palette;
       //palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
       //this->setPalette(palette);


       myDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
       myDB.setDatabaseName(Path_to_DB);
       QFileInfo checkFile(Path_to_DB);

       if(checkFile.isFile())
       {
           if(myDB.open())
           {
             ui->label->setText("The database is connected");
           }

       }else{
           ui->label->setText("No file found!");
       }


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    myDB.close();
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(!myDB.isOpen()){
        qDebug() << " No connection to db";
        return;
    }

    QString wordInput;
    wordInput = ui->lineEdit->text();

    QSqlQuery qry;

    qry.prepare("SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM Nepali WHERE Column1  = :input");
    qry.bindValue(":input",wordInput);

    if(qry.exec())
    {
        ui->debug->setText(" Checking output!");

      while (qry.next())
      {
         // Retrieve Values from select statement
         QString inputWord = qry.value(0).toString();
         QString wordDefinition = qry.value(1).toString();

         // Display values
         ui->output->setText(wordDefinition);
      }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "query failed to execute";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work now. The query is correctly locating the words, but how do I display the definition?  In other words, how do I retrieve the definition from the table and display it on labeltext ?   I suppose I might ned to make a change in my query right? Perhaps, like wordDef = qry.prepare("SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM Nepali WHERE Column1 and Column2  = :input");   and display like :  ui->output->setText(wordDef);         By the way, words are  entered by user and the app will output the definition.

Comment: Awesome!  No, the query already retrieves the values from both columns (the word and the definition).  You just have to extract those values.  I edited this answer with the code that extracts the values from the query (this is done right after qry.next()).  You can then display the values, and in my answer it will just display the definition, but you can display it how you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

After declaring the qry variable the code should look like this:

```
qry.prepare("SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM tableName WHERE Column1 = :input");
qry.bindValue(":input",wordInput);
if(qry.exec())
{
  if (qry.next())
  {
    // Extract the results from the SELECT statement
    QString inputWord = qry.value(0).toString();
    QString wordDefinition = qry.value(1).toString();

    // Then use the values for whatever you wish.
  } 
}
```

Comment: I tried your idea but it didn't work. I tried going through each line, and when I put this line of code after       if( qry.exec()){     ui->label->setText(" test output"); it never output that, so that means if statement is always false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need comma before `WHERE`. Also, I guess that you are comparing `Column1` with `wordInput`, not `Column2`.

```
if(qry.exec("SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM some_table WHERE Column1='"+ wordInput+"'"))
```

Edit: you don't mention a table you are selecting from.